# What is Hinduism's View on extraterrestrials?

Tags: philosophy, science, earth, astronomy

Different Religions have surprisingly diverse approaches to the issue of possible extraterrestrial life. What is Hindu scripture's view on existence of extraterrestrial life?

https://www.hinduwebsite.com/random/prometheus.asp

Comment: This is a dup. of [What do Hindus believe about extra-terrestrials?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44/what-do-hindus-believe-about-extra-terrestrials)

Comment: Thank you, that question was what exactly I was looking for.